# VBA workbooks.open

Tags: excel, vba

I run this code on VBA that used to work. The issue comes at `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilePath)` where the "error 9 out of range" appear. The problem is that the first file of the folder is actally opened and even thought this file has been opened, the error message still appear saying that I am out of range. I don't understand why it manage to open this file and in the same time find an error at exactly the line where I ask VBA to open the file.

```vb
Sub OpenFilesFromFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FilePath As String
        FolderPath = "S:\GESTION_ASS\Coordination Internationale\Global\_Monthly Asset Inventory Report (MAIRe)\1. Consolidation\Country data for macro\"
        FilePath = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
        Do While FilePath <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilePath)
            FilePath = Dir
        Loop
End Sub
```

I tried to use other files, to rewrite the macro, to change the path, to not use set and just write Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilePath). The code was working last week but not anymore

Comment: Calling `Workbooks.Open` on an already open file can cause issues.

Comment: Did you try to check to see if the workbook is already open first?   Loop through the workbooks `Application.Workbooks`

Answer (score 0):

- If the workbook is opened, `Set wb = Workbooks(FilePath)` gets the object reference, otherwise open it with `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilePath)`

```vb
Sub OpenFilesFromFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    FolderPath = "S:\GESTION_ASS\Coordination Internationale\Global\_Monthly Asset Inventory Report (MAIRe)\1. Consolidation\Country data for macro\"
    FilePath = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While FilePath <> ""
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(FilePath)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilePath)
        End If
        FilePath = Dir
        Set wb = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub
```